# IdM on apps we host for a client

Tags: authentication, authorization, appsec

We're looking at hosting some of a client's existing applications in our environment.

My current thinking is we will have an encrypted channel back to the client's network over which authentication and authorisation (as well as user traffic) will travel.

This seems preferable to implementing my own IdM and then having to keep them in synch' with the client's directories.

Any thoughts or alternative suggestions? Is this a good idea?